# Include custom css in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app

## ui.R

```
data("iris")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = "mystyle.css",
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab 1", "Hello"),
    div(id = "box1", style="color:#0000FF", selectInput("boxplot1", "Choose a dataset:",
                choices = c(list("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")))),
    div(id = "box2", selectInput("boxplot1", "Choose a dataset:",
                choices = c(list("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"))))
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot_boxplot"))
)
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  filtered <- reactive({
    iris %>%
      filter(Sepal.Length >= 0)
  })

  output$plot_boxplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
      geom_point(size = 4) + 
      geom_boxplot() +
      ylab("Sepal Length")  +
      stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=4) 
  })


  # Generate a summary of the dataset
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    summary(dataset)
  })

  # Show the first "n" observations
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })
})
```

This all works fine. However I would like to include some custom CSS.

If I take my my first input box, wrap it into a div statement and include some .css like this:

```
    div(id = "box1", style="color:#0000FF", selectInput("boxplot1", "Choose a dataset:",
            choices = c(list("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")))),
```

It works. However, for organisational purposes I would like to store it a seperate .css file. If I create in my www folder and include a link:

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = "mystyle.css",
```

And add the following to the file mystyle.css:

```
#box1{
 width: 20%;
 height: 100px;
 style="color:#0000FF";
}
```

I dont get the same result. Check all the code here:

## mystyle.css

```
#box1{
 width: 20%;
 height: 100px;
 style="color:#0000FF";
}
```

## ui.R

```
data("iris")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = "mystyle.css",
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab 1", "Hello"),
    div(id = "box1", selectInput("boxplot1", "Choose a dataset:",
                choices = c(list("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")))),
    div(id = "box2", selectInput("boxplot1", "Choose a dataset:",
                choices = c(list("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"))))
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot_boxplot"))
)
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

# Define server logic required to summarize and view the selected dataset
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  filtered <- reactive({
    iris %>%
      filter(Sepal.Length >= 0)
  })

  output$plot_boxplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
      geom_point(size = 4) + 
      geom_boxplot() +
      ylab("Sepal Length")  +
      stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=4) 
  })


  # Generate a summary of the dataset
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    summary(dataset)
  })

  # Show the first "n" observations
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })
})
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using [IncludeCSS()](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/include.html), like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361182/how-can-i-simply-add-a-css-file-to-change-the-background-color-for-my-shiny-app)?
could it be that your .CSS file is not saved in your *www* folder as suggested in [shiny's tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)?